# Cannot resolve symbol error

Tags: java, android, variables, listener, numberpicker

I have been trying and trying to figure this out, but with each change I make,  new error comes up. What I'd like to do is store the values from the numberpickers (I have 2 of them as you can probably see), and then be able to use these values later on. I would like to use them in the Toast message below and in a new activity called countdown once I fix this problem. I get error messages saying that mainTime and snoozeTime are redundant under the MyListener and MyListener2 classes, and "cannot resolve symbol" when I try to use them in my string.

```
public void openCD(View v) {

    class MyListener implements NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPickerMain, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            int mainTime = newVal;
        }
    }

    class MyListener2 implements NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPickerSnooze, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            int snoozeTime = newVal;
        }
    }

    String confirmation = "Your shower is set for " + MyListener.mainTime + " minutes with a " 
            + MyListener2.snoozeTime + " minute snooze. Enjoy your shower!";
    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), confirmation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent countdown=new Intent(this, CountDown.class);
    startActivity(countdown);
}
```

Comment: Declare your `mainTime, snoozeTime` Globally to access its values outside the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out as below:

```
int mainTime=0,snoozeTime=0; 

public void openCD(View v) {

    class MyListener implements NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPickerMain, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            mainTime = newVal;
        }
    }

    class MyListener2 implements NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPickerSnooze, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            snoozeTime = newVal;
        }
    }

    String confirmation = "Your shower is set for " + mainTime + " minutes with a " 
            + snoozeTime + " minute snooze. Enjoy your shower!";
    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), confirmation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent countdown=new Intent(this, CountDown.class);
    startActivity(countdown);
}
```

Comment: And this is different from my answer in... what ?

Comment: Oops, I honestly didn't even know how to do that! Marked it correct now. Thanks again for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
int mainTime = newVal;
```

you declare the variable locally, which means that it won't be recognized outside of the method.

Same applies to:

```
int snoozeTime = newVal;
```

In order to fix the issue, declare these variables as instance variables (in the class level) and when you assign them, just do the assignment, without a declaration (declaring the type):

```
mainTime = newVal;
```